# PS3 super slim bricked

Tags: ps3

I have a ps3 super slim and it is bricked. It turns on but does not deliver any image (tv keeps saying that there is no signal) and the controls do not recognize it (it keeps blinking all the red lights). It does not turn off until I remove the power cable or keep the power button pressed for around 10 seconds.

It started one day when I took it to a friends house and when I brought it back it stopped working. Nothing happened to it. I have never lost sight on it.

Any ideas on how to bring it back to life? I hope I'm able to do it because I have already lost one with YLOD.

Comment: Are you definitely sure your HDMI cable (or whichever cable you plug your PS3 to your TV with) is correctly plugged in? In doubt, try plugging your PS3 with both HDMI **and** A/V cable to your TV, then switch input to one or the other to see if any one cable works. You may also simply be observing the *wrong* HDMI input. Modern TVs usually feature multiple HDMI inputs.

Comment: I have tried with more than one cable and I'm sure it was plugged. And there is one reason I would discard this problem, the controls does not recognize the console. If it was the image output problem the controls would be working, right?

Comment: Have you tried [booting your PS3 in recovery mode](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3-Support/How-to-access-the-PlayStation-3-Recovery-Menu/td-p/19195118)?

Comment: Tried but I don't get the double beep. I get a bip when turning it on and a bip on turning it off... I followed exactly what this guy did on this video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNYz9YbpQC4

Comment: I don't know what more you could try, sorry I wasn't more helpful :(

Comment: I don't know anything about the PS3 but if you can take it apart and make sure nothing is loose, that might be an idea. I'm not sure it if it has some anti-tampering alarm system though, I'd make sure it doesn't first.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect us to do; from the info you've given us, it sounds like it's completely dead.  No video, no controller recognition, power button unresponsive.  You might want to take it to a repair shop, see what they can figure out.

Comment: Sony announced Super Slim in September 2012, so I guess that you still have warranty on it. Why don't you just bring it back to the shop where you bought it and let them do the reparation/replacement?

Comment: Try and re-call what happened at your friend's house. If you played a certain game that you don't normally play it may off-set the system. I would try to look up tech support for PS3 and talk about your system's symptoms like the flashing lights.

Answer (score 1):

From experience it does sound like the display output is set wrong. The above information is a tad bit wrong, because you do not go into recovery mode to reset the display.

Try this it may work it may not, but it's worth trying it the right way.

1. Take your controller, turn it over, stick a pencil lead or pin or something down into the reset hole, and press the button.
2. Hook up the controller to the system via the supplied usb cable.
3. Press the PS (Home) button on the control or turn on the system via the power button.

This should fix your controller issue which you need to fix before trying to reset the display correctly.  If the controller has any sort of surge or anything when charging it will do this, and it happens a lot when you use something besides the console to charge the controller. It is basically just resetting and pairing the controller again.

If the controller reset works, and the lights stop blinking turn off the console via holding down the power button. Do not unhook the cord.

1. Remove your hdmi or av cable from the console. If it's hdmi remove it from the tv as well, cut the tv on, and back off.
2. tightly plug in the hdmi or av cable to both the console and tv. Move the cable so that it's not coiled up.  HDMI cables will break pretty easily.
3. Press and hold the power button on the console until it beeps for a second time.  This is display reset mode, and not recovery mode.
4. IF the display comes up cut on the controller press left then X.

I know this sounds almost like the same thing posted above, but again that's saying go into recovery mode, which is the wrong place to be.  Also, if the hard drive is corrupted it will pop up on screen and tell you that you need to fix it. It won't mess up your video settings, because it will automatically set to the lowest quality for your video connection.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some things that can help you:

1. Whenever you switch your cable output, the ps3 also switches it's output. Make sure when there is no picture due to this problem to turn off the game console, then turn on, hold down the power button for approx. 5 Seconds, there will be a BEEP. Let go of power button, the ps3 has then switched back to the output it is currently plugged in and will work.

What this will do for you is basically reset the console and reconfigure the settings to allow tv images.

2. If your ps3 turns on but does not boot up just stays a black screen most likely the hard drive got corrupted.

This maybe from your friends house.

Information from: http://www.fixya.com/support/t267347-powers_but_no_picture.

Comment: This is still completely unhelpful.  The comments have already stated he's tried recovery mode, and it doesn't work.

Comment: @fbueckert Then it's corrupted.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure the hard drive's gone; there could be MANY different things wrong with it, beyond just the hard drive.

Comment: @fbueckert and what pray tell may that be?

Comment: Uh...any other part that makes up the PS3?  Single, or multiple parts.  Hard drive failure could be one of them, but there's really not enough information (and we don't really have the expertise) to diagnose what's wrong with this PS3.